# How can I query for min/max values over several subintervals at once in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite3 table with a timestamp column and another column with a certain value.
To get the overall min/max of the values I can query:

```
SELECT timestamp, max(value), min(value) from myTable;
```

The result is a single line.

But is there a way to query for the individual min/max values for equally sized subintervals?
For example, I want to consider intervals of size 10 (including left, but excluding right boundary): 
[0,10), [10,20), [20,30), ...
The desired result would then be several lines and look something like this:

```
timestamp max(value) min(value)
    0          3         1
   10          5         2
   20         13         0
   30         42        24
```

Of course, it is easy to split up the overall query into several ones to get this result line-by-line, but is there a way to get it all in a **single** query?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself:
To get the min/max values for all subsequent 10s intervals, the following query appears to do the trick:

```
SELECT (timestamp / 10) * 10 as intervalStartTime, min(value), max(value) FROM Test GROUP BY intervalStartTime;
```

This is assuming that timestamp is of integer type, so (timestamp / 10) is truncated before it is multiplied again.